# JS not working on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, include

I have a file named "admin.js" loading some JS files. They get loaded in HTML but nothing works... im considering that im having jquery error, but i do not know almost anything about it. The fact is that the rendered html code is almost the same outputed from rails but the rails do not work.

Rails output:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/breakpoints.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.slimscroll.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="/assets/admin/fullcalendar.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.blockui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.cookie.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.flot.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.flot.resize.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.gritter.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="/assets/admin/jquery.uniform.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/date.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin/daterangepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
App.setPage("index");  // set current page
App.init(); // init the rest of plugins and elements
});
</script>
```

WORKING HTML OUTPUT:

```
<!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
<!-- Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>   
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/js/excanvas.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/respond.js"></script>    
<![endif]-->    
<script src="assets/breakpoints/breakpoints.js"></script>       
<script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.blockui.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>                
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
        App.setPage("index");  // set current page
        App.init(); // init the rest of plugins and elements
    });
</script>
```

Admin.js File that loads the JSs (and its actually working)

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, libjavascripts, vendorjavascripts,
// or vendorjavascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require admin/breakpoints
//= require admin/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min   
//= require admin/jquery.slimscroll.min
//= require admin/fullcalendar.min
//= require admin/bootstrap.min
//= require admin/jquery.blockui    
//= require admin/jquery.cookie
//= require admin/jquery.flot
//= require admin/jquery.flot.resize
//= require admin/jquery.gritter.min
//= require admin/jquery.uniform.min    
//= require admin/date
//= require admin/daterangepicker
```

And the admin.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body class="fixed-top">

    <%= yield %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "admin" %>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    App.setPage("index");  // set current page
    App.init(); // init the rest of plugins and element }
    );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I already tried many options. the fact is that when i paste the code from the original HTML just changing the paths for my rails app assets, it works, but i want to do this in correct rails structure and want to understand why it is happening... i got no error messages, but the controllers like accordions and stuff arent working.

Hope u guys can help.

Comment: What does your directory structure actually look like? You're telling sprockets to look inside an `admin` folder for your files, and this is evidend by the URLs generated by the pipeline. Yet your actual working code makes no reference to an admin subdirectory. Do your admin js files really exist inside an `admin` folder like you're referencing in sprockets?

Comment: i actually dont know what happened, but it just started to work... by itself.. lol.. go figure...